# How to Send a Any File Type through Redirect in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, treeview, download

I currently have a TreeView showing a directory in a web page. I don't think you can capture click events on a Node so instead I'm creating the navigation link to the same page which processes a parameter (path).

I've tried a couple things:

---

```
Response.ContentType = "text/txt";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.Write(file.ToString());
Response.End();
```

^^ The code above only really works for Text files (or whatever extension I want to define). ^^

---

The code below writes the file as a set of characters to the browser.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string path = Request["path"];

    if ((path != "") && (path != null))
    {
        Response.TransmitFile(path);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

---

Is there a good solution to this I'm just missing? I need to send any file with an option to save it when selected from a TreeView.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to set the Content Type and Disposition.

Answer (score 4):

Just got it working I think...

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best article I could find:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx

**File on disk**:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Image.jpg");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/images/image.jpg"));
Response.End();
```

**Generated file**:

```
Bitmap bmp = GenerateImage();     
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Image.jpg");     
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```